# Azure SWA - Nextjs Images not found

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app

Im trying to deploy a Next JS application on Azure's static web app service. I have the app building and running but the images are not rendering. From the console, it's reporting a 404 not found error.

> GET https://{url}.4.azurestaticapps.net/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Ficon%2FMessage.png&w=48&q=75 404 (Not Found)

```
<Image
  src="/images/icon/Message.png"
  alt="message"
  width={20}
  height={20}
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

My folder structure is:

```
- app
  - (public)
    - page.tsx
- public
  - images
    - icon
      - Message.png
```

I know the files are there, because I have some CSS which is rendering one of my images correctly.

```css
  const divStyle = {
    Width: '100%',
    backgroundImage: `url('/images/banner/banner-03.png')`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
  }
```

```json
{
  "name": "daisy-nextjs-setup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write . --ignore-path .prettierignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "daisyui": "^2.51.3",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.4",
    "next": "^13.2.4",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "export"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     npm explore # Browse an installed package
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the image path is currently linked to the

```
 /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Ficon%2FMessage.png&w=48&q=75
```

location, which is generated by`Next.js`during the build process.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to modify the image path to properly reference the image stored within the _next folder. You can achieve this by replacing the traditional img tag with the next/image component. Here's an example for clarification:-

```
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image
  src="/images/icon/Message.png"
  alt="message"
  width={20}
  height={20}
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

I have referred this [Github Repository](https://github.com/xizon/fullstack-nextjs-app-template?tab=readme-ov-file#) by @xizon. And the repository with the images were loaded successfully in Azure static web app. Refer this sample repository and implement same logic in your project.

I cloned this repository locally and built it using the commands below, Which generated a build folder **`out`**, Then I utilized this **`out`** folder in my Azure static web app deployment yaml file in Github as well as Devops by setting **`skip_build:true`**:-

[Static build:-](https://github.com/xizon/fullstack-nextjs-app-template?tab=readme-ov-file#export-your-nextjs-application-to-static-html)

```js
npm install
npm run dev
npm run build
npm run export
npm run export:fix
npm run export:test
```

**Github pipeline:-**

```yaml
app_location: "out" 
api_location: "" 
output_location: "" 
skip_app_build: true
```

***Complete pipeline:-***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_KIND_DESERT_053CF2E03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "out" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "" 
          skip_app_build: true
          

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_KIND_DESERT_053CF2E03 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Azure DevOps pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/out'
    skip_app_build: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'xxxxxxxx42498'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: H, thanks for the response. 

I am building images using the next/image. I did notice that your build scripts use the 'out' folder. But if I use this I get an invalid directory error so I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks, Adam

Comment: It seems like how you're building the next app is different to what I am. If you're skipping the app build, does this mean you're running the app build yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am building it locally and generating out folder then adding that out folder in my repository, by removing it from .gitignore file. And then trying the deployment again by specifying out folder as directory to build and deploy application

Comment: As, Github action will not build it properly, Thus I have given commands to build the static content of app

Comment: Im getting the error "missing script: "export"

Comment: Complete error? Is this error while you build and deploy app in github actions?

Comment: So if I run your static build commands on my local machine: npm install, npm run dev, npm build when I get to npm export I get the error that the export script is missing.

Comment: Ive added the error to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Did you try npm run export?

Comment: npm install,
npm run dev,
npm run build,
npm run export,
npm run export:fix,
npm run export:test >> Try this commands

Comment: Ive tried npm run export, npm run fix and npm run export:fix. None of them work.

Comment: Check your package.json is similar to this file in the gihub link - https://github.com/xizon/fullstack-nextjs-app-template/blob/main/package.json